# PHP SESSIONS data getting cleared?

Tags: php, session

I am able to print out the data contained in `$_SESSIONS` right before a header(Location) redirect and a `die()` after the header redirect.

However, when I am redirected, there is no data contained in `$_SESSIONS`. I've checked the `session_id()` that they're the same. I've tried `session_write_close()` right before the redirect and that doesn't help. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Is there in both scripts at the begining you have `session_start()` ?

Comment: Yes, I have a require('functions.php') at the top of my script and at the very end of functions.php I have session_start();
(The header redirect is to the same page so I'm only dealing with 1 page here)

Comment: redirected to the same domain?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on index.php and my header redirect is: header("Location: index.php");

Comment: *Location* requires a full path btw

Comment: not related but you could `return` or `exit` as opposed to `die`

Comment: @ring0 depends on connection protocol version.

Comment: What is the difference between using return or exit as compared to die?

Comment: @CORRUPT [Most browsers tolerate it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) but it should normally be a full path

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: Sorry everyone, it turns out that the web hosting I'm using decided to do something weird/unconventional with the session save path...and is poorly documented/pointed out.

So to anyone out there if you think you have everything correct, double check your hosting place because that might save you hours of research and testing!

Comment: Is this not an issue of the fact that you're using $_SESSIONS instead of $_SESSION? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `$_SESSION` rather than `$_SESSIONS`. Also, make sure the current session is loaded in the script with `session_start();`

If you are sure the code is correct, run the script a couple of times and check your PHP session temporary directory. The problem could very possibly be the PHP server does not have the correct permissions to write to the session files directory.